# How to Delete product has been seleted

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete a product, but it's doesn't show successful. I do not know how to get the id of that product to delete

My button `onClick = {handleDelete}` is import from component in other folder. I try to create `handleDelete` function, but I missing something in this case.

This is my code for that section

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import Loading from "../../components/Loading";
import Button from "../../components/Button/index"
import firebaseApp from "../../api/config";

const ProductTableList = ({
  products,
  loading,
  fetchProductRequest
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductRequest();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);


const firebaseDb = firebaseApp.database();
const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState("");

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Loading />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }

 

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const productId = firebaseDb.ref().push().key;
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure to delete this record?")) {
      firebaseDb
        .ref("products")
        .child(`products/${productId}`)
        .remove((err) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          else setCurrentId("");
        });
    }
  }

  const handleUpdate = (event) => {
    //TODO
  }
  return (
    <Table striped bordered hover className="product-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th className="image">Image</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {!!products && products.length > 0 ? (
          products.map((product, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{index}</td>
                <td>{product.image}</td>
                <td>{product.name}</td>
                <td>{product.category}</td>
                <td>{product.price}</td>
                <td>{product.description}</td>
                <td>
                  <Button onClick={handleDelete} btnText="Delete" />&nbsp;
                  <Button onClick={handleUpdate} btnText="Update" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })
        ) :
          (
            <tr><td className="center-title">Product list is empty!</td></tr>
          )}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  )
}

export default ProductTableList;
```

Can anyone help me? How do I delete the product that I have selected

Can anyone explain or support for me why? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

[Hooks rely on getting called the in the same order every time to work correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). They cannot to be called conditionally.

However in your component if `loading` is true you return from the function early, thereby stopping the `currentId` `useState` from being called on some renders. This means you are calling the `useState` hook conditionally which is not allowed.

To fix this move the state call to be above the `if (loading) {` statement.